# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS freezing about every 10-15 seconds

Tags: nvidia

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS my desktop freezes up for about 1-3 seconds and this happens every 15-20 seconds even when doing very simple tasks such as browsing the internet or doing nothing at all. My system is completely updated and I have tried rebooting, no change.

Some System Information:
CPU: Intel® Core™ i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8
Graphics: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
Nvidia Version: 440.64
OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS  64-bit

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Im seeing this as well. Were you able to get a solution?

Comment: Same here again with GeForce GTX 1060 M. Using Kubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Use the `top` command to find the biggest memory-consuming processes. It it happens to be a web browser, close a few tabs. If it's some long-running daemon or server process, restart it. (If a daemon or server chronically consumes more and more memory, that's a bug - file it!) If it's something you don't recognize, ask about it in AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, Ubuntu 20.04 hangs/freezes even though I have 8 GB of RAM and an i7.

I could temporary fix this issue in my side, by expanding the swap partition from 2 GB to 16 GB

I am not sure but I think there is problem in Ubuntu 20.04 memory management. Here on my side it keep consuming memory, then when both memory and swap are full, the computer starts to freeze and hang.

The solution's steps are:

1. Check the amount of swap you have

   ```
   grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
   ```
2. Turn off the swap process

   ```
   sudo swapoff -a
   ```
3. Resize the swap (in my case I expanded it to 16 GB)

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=16
   ```
4. Attach the swap to the partition

   ```
   sudo mkswap /swapfile
   ```
5. Activate swap (enable it)

   ```
   sudo swapon /swapfile
   ```
6. See the new swap size

   ```
   grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo
   ```

Done.

---

References:

- [Bogdan Cornianu - Change swap size in Ubuntu 18.04 or newer](https://bogdancornianu.com/change-swap-size-in-ubuntu/) (thanks man)

Comment: A "problem" with memory management would be an important bug! However, I think the OP has presented insufficient information to reach that conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution of mine:

- Disable all sleep/blank/switch off from power management settings (set to never).
- Change lock from Keyboard > Application Shortcuts from xflock4 to i3lock. Need to install i3lock first (`apt install i3lock`).
- Disable or remove [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg?hl=enhttps://) extension if you install it.
- Try opening your chrome then block url, hover your pointer above it and leave it at that state if none of above worked.
- Don't leave your notebook charged for too long (ex: overcharged or even fully charged) while locking (for notebook user)

Worked in my case except it will freeze after around 1 hour. I use Xubuntu with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score -1):

To boost the performance of your machine, simply empty your trash (recycle bin) and anything else that you don't need. Also, avoid opening many activities at once. This will help a lot!

Comment: You need to expand your answer with more information. This is a general suggestion, not an answer. The thing you are telling is really obvious and won't help much. As the poster reported their screen is freezing in periods of 10-15 seconds. So, your answer is not of much use in this case. Consider expanding your answer with more information. Refer to [answer].